# Inverting the MacOS's mouse X axis doesn't work with CGEventSetIntegerValueField

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to invert the mouse movement (specifically my Magic Trackpad 2) on X axis on Mac OS, AFAIK I will have to listen to the `NSEventMaskMouseMoved`, and do the modification on the `callback`. Here is what I have

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>


static CGEventRef callback(CGEventTapProxy proxy,
                            CGEventType type,
                            CGEventRef eventRef,
                            void *userInfo) {
    if (type == kCGEventMouseMoved) {
        // Get the original delta X value
        int64_t deltaX = CGEventGetIntegerValueField(eventRef, kCGMouseEventDeltaX);

        // Invert the delta X value
        int64_t invertedDeltaX = -deltaX;

        // Set the inverted delta X value back on the original event
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(eventRef, kCGMouseEventDeltaX, invertedDeltaX);

        NSLog(@"Original Delta X: %lld", deltaX);
        NSLog(@"Inverted Delta X: %lld", invertedDeltaX);

        return eventRef;
    }

    return eventRef;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CFMachPortRef tapPort = (CFMachPortRef)CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap,
                                               kCGTailAppendEventTap,
                                               kCGEventTapOptionDefault,
                                               NSEventMaskMouseMoved,
                                               callback,
                                               nil);

        if (tapPort) {
            NSLog(@"tapPort created %p", tapPort);
            
            CFRunLoopSourceRef tapSource = (CFRunLoopSourceRef)CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, tapPort, 0);
            
            if (tapSource) {
                NSLog(@"tapSource created %p", tapSource);
                
                CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetMain(), tapSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
                
//                CGEventTapEnable(tapSource, true);
                
                CFRunLoopRun();
            } else {
                NSLog(@"tapSource NOT created");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"tapPort NOT created");
        }
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On the log console, it seems everything's correct (I gave the Accessibiity permission). But the mouse movement event is not changed, unfortunately. Seems the `CGEventSetIntegerValueField` is not making any different.

Maybe I'm doing in a wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you check the mouse movement event?

Comment: @Willeke I use `CGEventTapCreate` with the `NSEventMaskMouseMoved` mask to listen the mouse movement event. And after the callback called, my mouse pointer doesn't get inverted

Comment: The mouse pointer and the events are both driven by the mouse or trackpad. Changing the events does not change the mouse pointer.